# Convex set as a set of numbers only?

Tags: convex-optimization

Can a set of numbers (not tuples) be called a convex set?

I have read this article:

[on the medium.com website](https://medium.com/@rhome/convex-optimization-unconstrained-836a44182f9d)

where at the beginning is written an underlined text, saying that "where the domain of $f$ is a convex set" ("convex set" there is underlined). Function $f$ is one variable function.

My idea of a convex set is a $2D$ or $3D$ shape where every point on a line segment $AB,$ where points $A,B$ belong to the set, also belongs to the set.

Comment: "Convex" works for subsets of any (real) vector space, and $\mathbb R$ is a perfectly good vector space. You can call it $\mathbb R^1$ if that makes you feel better.

Comment: Yes. It did answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Jan You can close it as a duplicate.